# How to read materialized view created in kafka through java code

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have created a materialized view in kafka stream, I am unable to find java code snippet to read materialized view.

Could anyone suggest the code to read a materialized view and create a HashMap (assuming key is String and value is Long).

One sample snippet to create kafka materialized view "queryable-store-name" is:

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
 KTable<Integer, Integer> table = builder.table(
   "topicName",
   Materialized.as("queryable-store-name"));
```

Comment: Not sure that this mean: "I have created a materialized view in kafka" -- Overall, the question is unclear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax: Thanks for your comment. I have edited my question.

Comment: Why do you want to create a HashMap? You can just do key-value lookups directly on the create KTable. In general, I think you are looking for "Interactive Queries" feature: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax: thank you so much for pointing to correct documentation.